# Swing JCheckBox - set string according to ticked-unticked

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I have created a window to appear when my program loads, and give the user the option to make it not appear through a checkbox. I also have the .properties file set and know how to update the fields etc.

What I do not know is what event to use, so when the user ticks the checkbox, the string is set to "yes" and when the user un-ticks the string is set to "no".

edit for clarity.

properties file:

```
tipsVisible=yes
```

where the extra window appears:

```
public MainWindow() {
    initComponents();
    setIcon();     

    //read properties file
    if(showTips.equals("yes"))
    {
        Tips window = new Tips();
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
        window.setVisible(true);
}
```

my code to update the properties file

```
 private void updateProperties(String showHints) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("First.properties");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(in);
    in.close();

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("First.properties");
    props.setProperty("tipsVisible", showHints);
    props.store(out, null);
    out.close();
}
```

So what I need is on the even listener to change showHints to "yes" or "no" and send it to updateProperties();

Comment: The string ***should*** read 'Show on start-up". This approach of changing the string of the checkbox depending on state is not the 'path of least surprise' for the end user & thus should be avoided.

Comment: you need to do that in the action listener of the checkbox. Inside this you need to disable enable the window which most probably is a panel

Answer (score 3):

Use an ItemListener to respond when the user sets or unsets the checkbox..

Answer (score -1):

Massive brainfart. The heat is getting to me

```
 private void hintsCheckboxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    if(hintsCheckbox.isSelected())
    {
        showHints = "yes";
    }
    else
    {
        showHints = "no";
    }
    try {
        storeUpdatedProperties(showHints);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Tips.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Edited for completeness

Comment: no bro. If you do it this way you are simply enabling setting the flag but no action gets invoked. You would need to do this inside the action listener associated with the check box. And inside there you should be setting visible to false for the Hint panel.

Comment: @Acewin Didn't quite get what you mean. After this is done, showHints value is stored in the properties file, and accordigly the hints are shown or not on the next program run. Unless there is an action listener for isSelected(true) and isSelected(false) I don't see a better solution to this.

P.S. as I said, the heat is getting to me. This **is** inside the action listener.